# Flask: addt.l Decorators - ends up in def _endpoint_from_view_func() from the flask module

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

I am pretty new to coding, and just tried setting up a basic website from Flask Framework. As you can see below, **the correct String will be returned** from the wrapper function. After some debugging, I have found that the error occurs only and right after the def greet(): line is reached (body of greet() will not be entered) I ended up in the **scaffold.py** file from the flask module, **_endpoint_from_view_func()** to be exact. The details of this function, I have appended last below my own code and console output. As I am said, I am new so any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S: What I was trying to do was to set up a basic "Guess the number" game. For diversity the title of each page should take a different color. The game works by typing your name into the URL. Each promt (higher, lower, right) is accompanied by gif-images.

### Works (rtrns correct String)

```
def random_color(function):
    print("function was called")
    def wrapper_function(*args):
        colors = [
            "red",
            "orange",
            "yellow",
            "green",
            "blue",
            "purple"
        ]
        color = choice(colors)
        if len(args) > 0:
            old_string = function(args[0])
        else:
            old_string = function()
        new_string = old_string.replace('style="color:"', f'style="color:{color}"')
        print(new_string)
        return new_string
    return wrapper_function()
```

### Does not work:

```
@app.route("/")
@random_color
def greet():
    return '<h1 style="color:">Guess a number between 0 and 9</h1>' \
           '<img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/l0MYEw3Rjka9yuWTS/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e476gq68j4mlf22qmk3bqnkeg7mrxy2pray74x14vhn&rid=200w.webp&ct=g">'
```

### Console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/day-54-flask/server.py", line 47, in <module>
    def greet():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 440, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 56, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1047, in add_url_rule
    endpoint = _endpoint_from_view_func(view_func)  # type: ignore
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 750, in _endpoint_from_view_func
    return view_func.__name__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'. Did you mean: '__ne__'?
```

### The function where the exception occurs:

```
def _endpoint_from_view_func(view_func: t.Callable) -> str:
    """Internal helper that returns the default endpoint for a given
    function.  This always is the function name.
    """
    assert view_func is not None, "expected view func if endpoint is not provided."
    return view_func.__name__
```

Thanks for reading this through. As I am specifically training on decorators, I would greatly appreciate a solution that features a decorator. I already made shift with another solution not featuring the additional decorator, which is functional ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is this:

return wrapper_function()

it should be

return wrapper_function

Without the parenthesis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing

```py
@random_color
@app.route("/")
def():
   ....
```

As far as I'm seeing Flask is looking for the @app.route('/') but is seeing the return of your @random_color.

Since I'm unable to see the code for your choice(colors) I experimented with the return.

```py
def random_color(function):
    print("function was called")
    def wrapper_function(*args):
        colors = [
            "red",
            "orange",
            "yellow",
            "green",
            "blue",
            "purple"
        ]
        color = choice(colors)
        if len(args) > 0:
            old_string = function(args[0])
        else:
            old_string = function()
        new_string = old_string.replace('style="color:"', f'style="color:{color}"')
        print(new_string)
        return new_string
    return "ThisIsAString"
```

And when doing this

```py
@random_color
@app.route("/")
def greet():
  print(greet)
  return '<h1 style="color:">Guess a number between 0 and 9</h1>''<img src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/l0MYEw3Rjka9yuWTS/200w.webp?cid=ecf05e476gq68j4mlf22qmk3bqnkeg7mrxy2pray74x14vhn&rid=200w.webp&ct=g">'
```

It prints "ThisIsAString" is this the type of behavior you are trying to achieve?